# How to import non amd library ember-cli

Tags: ember.js, ember-cli

I am using Ember-CLI and now I faced the problem of importing AmplifyJS in my project. I downloaded Amplify using Bower however the library is not in an ES6 format. Therefore, when I try to use it in my project, I simply can't import it.

Basically I would want to do:

```
import Amplify from amplify;

//use amplify here
```

*Brocfile.js*

```
app.import('bower_components/amplify/lib/amplify.js');
```

Since a lot of libraries are no in the ES6 format yet, my question is: "Is there a way to easily import or use ES5 librairies in ES6".

If not, what is the recommended way of doing that in Ember?

Answer (score 1):

You can't `import Amplify from amplify;` because it's not a module.

You've almost got it but just don't try to import the library. You need to reference it as a global the way that you would outside of an ember-cli app.

From the docs:

> Provide the asset path as the first and only argument:
>
> ```
> app.import('bower_components/moment/moment.js');
> ```
>
> From here you would use the package as specified by it’s documentation, usually a global variable. In this case it would be:
>
> ```
> import Ember from 'ember';
> /* global moment */
> // No import for moment, it's a global called `moment`
>
> // ...
> var day = moment('Dec 25, 1995');
> ```
>
> Note: Don’t forget to make JSHint happy by adding a `/* global MY_GLOBAL */` to your module, or by defining it within the predefs section of your .jshintrc file.
>
> -- http://www.ember-cli.com/#standard-non-amd-asset

Comment: So basically Ember is pushing really hard on ES6 but elsewhere we can't really use it properly,.. that's a bummer

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. That library wasn't written as ES6 modules. It's not Ember's fault... If it was written as ES6 modules you could use it as such.

Comment: Thank you so much for the /* global ... */ advice, I was only missing this part to make my ESLint cooperate.

Answer (score 0):

If you look at line 15 of the code https://github.com/mikehostetler/amplify/blob/master/lib/amplify.js#L15, library is attaching itself to `global` which is passed in here https://github.com/mikehostetler/amplify/blob/master/lib/amplify.js#L124

So basically you can directly use the global version of library anywhere like `amplify.subscribe(...)`